# VAO Rendering incorrectly in LWJGL

Tags: java, opengl, render, lwjgl

I am trying to use VAOs to render and am having trouble with incorrect rendering.
I do have a little experience in the subject but not a huge amount.

This is my binding Code:

```
//RawModel is just a type to store vao id and number of indices.
public RawModel loadToVao(float[] positions, int[] indices){
    //create VAO and bind it
    int vaoID = GL30.glGenVertexArrays();
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(vaoID);

    //create index buffer
    int indexVBO = GL15.glGenBuffers();
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexVBO);
    IntBuffer indexBuffer = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(indices.length);
    indexBuffer.put(indices);
    indexBuffer.flip();
    GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer , GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    //create vertex buffer
    int positionVBO = GL15.glGenBuffers();
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, positionVBO);
    FloatBuffer vertBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(positions.length);
    vertBuffer.put(positions);
    vertBuffer.flip();
    GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertBuffer , GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, false, 0,0);
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
    return new RawModel(vaoID, indices.length);
}
```

This is my render code:

```
GL30.glBindVertexArray(obj.getVaoID());
GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
GL11.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_POINTS, 0, sphere.getRawModel().getSize());
GL11.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, sphere.getRawModel().getSize());
GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
```

I render both points and Triangles just to see what is going wrong. eventually will only be triangles.

This code always seems to give me a point at the objects centre which should not be there. It also has incorrect grouping of elements so triangles render completely wrong.

If anyone could help it would be great.
Thanks

Comment: if anyone needs anymore information just ask and I will try to provide.

Comment: One thing that looks odd is that you create an index array, but don't use it. If you want to draw with indices, you need to call `glDrawElements()`, not `glDrawArrays()`. But based on the symptoms, that might not be your only problem.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Thanks. That worked :) complete goof from me :P